# How to implement custom exception for user input

Tags: java, exception

This is my method where I ask user to enter name, last name, etc. of new user: How to implement exception here so if user enter integer show him exception for first name and last name?

```
 @Override
public void addNewPassenger(ArrayList<Passenger> passengersList) {

    System.out.println("Creating new passenger!");

    System.out.print("Add ID of passenger: ");
    passenger.setId(scanner.nextInt());
    scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Add name of passenger: ");
    passenger.setFirstName(scanner.nextLine());

    System.out.print("Add last name of passenger: ");
    passenger.setLastName(scanner.nextLine());

    System.out.print("Add email of passenger: ");
    passenger.setEmail(scanner.nextLine());

    System.out.print("Add balance of passenger: ");
    passenger.setBalance(scanner.nextDouble());


    System.out.println("You added a new passenger!");


    passengersList.add(passenger);
}
```

Also I have class Passenger where with those fields and getters and setters ofc.

I want to create the class that will contain the exceptions, then in that class to create a method to check the exception in case the user enters a number instead of a letter.

I already saw some examples but none shows how to make a special class for exceptions and then have special methods for exceptions where the user enters numbers instead of letters, letters instead of numbers and etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new exception class:

```
class NoNumbersException extends Exception
{
    NoNumbersException(){ 
        super("You can not enter numbers here."); 
    }
}
```

When you hit an illegal input (e.g. "1"), you can throw the exception:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    try{
        System.out.print("Add name of passenger: ");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        if (name.contains("1")) {
            throw new NoNumbersException();
        }
    } catch(NoNumbersException nne) {
        System.out.println(nne.getMessage());
    }
}
```